# Increase Date to specific day of the following month

Tags: sql-server, fastreport

I want to take the current date and increase it to the 15th of the following month.

```
[<Date> #dmmm 15, yyyy]

Result:
Oct 15, 2012

DESIRED RESULT:
Nov 15, 2012
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?  Do you want it to increase when stored in the database, etc?  I am only assuming it is a database question with your tags (nothing else indicates your environment or what you are trying to do).  It may be more obvious to someone else, just trying to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the date you're starting with is the 15th, then you can perform this operation:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm, 1, [DateField])
```

However, if we don't know what the starting day is we'll have to construct a date we can start with first, so you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm, 1,
    CAST(
        CAST(DATEPART(mm, [DateField]) AS VARCHAR) +
        '/15/' +
        CAST(DATEPART(yy, [DateField]) AS VARCHAR)
    AS DATETIME))
```

From Aaron - here is how I would write this to avoid shorthand, regional issues and improper casting:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(CHAR(6), DateColumn, 112) + '15')
FROM ...
```

Comment: @JamieS, not a problem, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: Be very careful about two things here: (1) cast to varchar without length. It's ok in this scenario but [is not a good practice to encourage in general](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). (2) This seems to rely on m/d/y date format. Try this code with `SET LANGUAGE BRITISH`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thank you for the comments. I will remember that casting without a length is **bad** and further, can you edit my post to show me an example of how this work across languages? Or even point me to a post on it so I can learn? I know you hold a very high rep in this realm.